# How to resolve "you card was decline " in Stripe payment gateway. in swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

Hello guys i have implemented strive payment Below my code but it says your card blocked.
this function is used to make the payment successfully.Attaching image also in this i am calling api to get the secrete key from the backend with that secrete key i am doing the payment with stripe below is the code please code review the and help me and get me out of this.

```
[![I have added the image to which that error is coming][1]][1]

    //this is the method to make the payment here
        func pay(){
        
        //Secrete key
        guard let setupIntentClientSecret = setupIntentClientSecret else {
            return;
        }
        
        // Collect card details
        let cardParams = self.paymentTextField.cardParams
       
        
        // Collect the customer's email to know which customer the Payment Method belongs to.

        let billingDetails = STPPaymentMethodBillingDetails()

        if  let email =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: keyParameter.email.rawValue) as? String{
            billingDetails.email = email
        }
        
        var name = ""
        if  let nameStr =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: keyParameter.firstname.rawValue) as? 
        String{
            name = nameStr
        }
        
        if  let LastnameStr =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: keyParameter.lastname.rawValue) 
            as? String{
         name = (name+" "+LastnameStr).capitalized
        }

        billingDetails.name = name
        if  let phone =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: keyParameter.phone.rawValue) as? String{
          billingDetails.phone = phone
        }
        
       // Create SetupIntent confirm parameters with the above
        let paymentMethodParams = STPPaymentMethodParams(card: cardParams, 
            billingDetails:billingDetails, 
         metadata: nil)

        let setupIntentParams = STPSetupIntentConfirmParams(clientSecret: setupIntentClientSecret)

        setupIntentParams.paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams
        
        // Complete the setup
        let paymentHandler = STPPaymentHandler.shared()
        paymentHandler.confirmSetupIntent(withParams: setupIntentParams, authenticationContext: self) 
         { 
           (status, setupIntent, error) in
            switch (status) {
            case .failed:
              //Display message if failed
                break
            case .canceled:
             //Cancelled 
                break
            case .succeeded:
               //Success
                break
             default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your card being declined is not a coding question, but you can check your response and logs to see why it was declined. The decline codes are here: https://stripe.com/docs/declines/codes

Comment: Also, you would never use a secret key on the frontend. It should never leave the backend of your integration.